# Ubuntu Update Manager is showing an error message

Tags: update-manager

The error message is as follows:

```
Could not initialize the package information
An unresolvable problem occurred while initializing the package information.
Please report this bug against the 'update-manager' package and include the following error message:
'E:Malformed line 57 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (dist parse)'
```

Answer (score 0):

This means that there is something wrong with line 57 in your sources file. We need to fix that.

First, open up a terminal. To do so, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. In the prompt, type the following

```
gksu gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Enter your password when prompted. This command opens up the file `sources.list` in a text editor so we can edit it.

You need to go down to line 57. You don't have to count the lines, you can look at the bottom right corner where you can see Ln 1, Col 1. So go to line 57. Let's say it looks something like this:

```
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu main
```

You need to change it to look like this:

```
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring main
```

Notice the difference between them? The difference is the word **raring**. However, this word corresponds to the Ubuntu version you are running. So for example, if your Ubuntu version is Ubuntu 12.10, the word should be **quantal**. To know which word you're supposed to put, look at the other lines in the file, you'll find the word in all the other lines. Once you add the word in, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to save the file, and close the window.

Now go to the update manager and check if the problem is solved or not.

Comment: line no 57 is deb http://archive.canonical.com/precise partner

Comment: Change it to look like this: `deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner`. If the error persists, can you edit your question and post the contents of your sources.list file?

Comment: Thank you. It is done. Once again Thanks for great help.

Comment: You're welcome! Don't forget to mark the correct answer by hitting the check mark found at the left of the answer.